# How to use a hyperlink column in a workflow email

Tags: 2010, workflow, email, column, hyperlink

I'm creating a workflow "Send an Email" action in SharePoint Designer that needs to use a "Hyperlink or Picture" column from the Current Item.  Whenever I select the "Hyperlink or Picture" column using the "Add or Change Lookup" button the link shows up in the email formatted as "{Hyperlink}, {Description}" (ex. "http://www.google.com, Google").

How can I change it so that it just shows the Description as a hyperlink (ex. "[Google](http://www.google.com)")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workflow tools in SharePoint Designer 2010 has has a substring action available.   You should be able to utilize that to break full hyperlink field into pieces and extract the piece you want.